# Как обратиться к компоненту Bitrix через ajax?

Tags: битрикс

Доброго времени суток, сообщество! есть компонент bitrix:news.list , необходимо менять источник данных "IBLOCK_ID" при определённом изменение на странице, не могу понять как изменить значение "IBLOCK_ID" из скрипта, как правильно обратиться к компоненту ?

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался сам, передаю значение для "IBLOCK_ID" через сессию, так же можно передать же глобальную переменную.